# Print only specific content from array and nice print

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list it prints in a weird way. I just want to print out the names nothing more, with each name in a new line. How can I do that?

```
Player 1
Player 2
Player 3
Etc...
```

The php code which gets the info also has this. Don't know what it does but still maybe important to know.

```
    Header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );
    Header( 'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff' );
```

The output i have so far looks like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 1
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 1779
            [TimeF] => 29:39
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 2
            [Frags] => 1
            [Time] => 1691
            [TimeF] => 28:11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 3
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 1662
            [TimeF] => 27:42
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 4
            [Frags] => 1
            [Time] => 1540
            [TimeF] => 25:40
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 5
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 1495
            [TimeF] => 24:55
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 6
            [Frags] => 3
            [Time] => 1401
            [TimeF] => 23:21
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 7
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 1280
            [TimeF] => 21:20
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 8
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 1239
            [TimeF] => 20:39
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 9
            [Frags] => 1
            [Time] => 1126
            [TimeF] => 18:46
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 10
            [Frags] => 1
            [Time] => 492
            [TimeF] => 08:12
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 0
            [Name] => Player 11
            [Frags] => 0
            [Time] => 272
            [TimeF] => 04:32
        )

)
```

The php code i use is this.

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/../SourceQuery/bootstrap.php';

    use xPaw\SourceQuery\SourceQuery;

    // For the sake of this example
    Header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );
    Header( 'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff' );

    // Edit this ->
    define( 'SQ_SERVER_ADDR', '1111111111111' );
    define( 'SQ_SERVER_PORT', 11111111 );
    define( 'SQ_TIMEOUT',     1 );
    define( 'SQ_ENGINE',      SourceQuery::SOURCE );
    // Edit this <-

    $Query = new SourceQuery( );

    try
    {
        $Query->Connect( SQ_SERVER_ADDR, SQ_SERVER_PORT, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );

print_r( $Query->GetPlayers( ) );


    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        echo $e->getMessage( );
    }
    finally
    {
        $Query->Disconnect( );
    }

?>
```

Comment: have you ever use foreach,while loop?

Comment: Lol just need foreach loop to acheive this and three answers posted :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else helped me so here is the answer.
It only prints names without array.

The code.

```html
foreach($Query->GetPlayers() as $player) {
  echo $player['Name'];
  echo "\n"; 
}
```

The complete code.

```html
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/../SourceQuery/bootstrap.php';
 
    use xPaw\SourceQuery\SourceQuery;
   
    // For the sake of this example
    Header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );
    Header( 'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff' );
   
    // Edit this ->
    define( 'SQ_SERVER_ADDR', 'SERVER IP' );
    define( 'SQ_SERVER_PORT', PORT );
    define( 'SQ_TIMEOUT',     1 );
    define( 'SQ_ENGINE',      SourceQuery::SOURCE );
    // Edit this <-
   
    $Query = new SourceQuery( );
   
    try
    {
        $Query->Connect( SQ_SERVER_ADDR, SQ_SERVER_PORT, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );
       
foreach($Query->GetPlayers() as $player) {
  echo $player['Name'];
  echo "\n"; 
}

 
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        echo $e->getMessage( );
    }
    finally
    {
        $Query->Disconnect( );
    }
   
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
<?php
foreach($input as $item) {
  echo $item['Name'];
}
?>
```

...and get yourself a good PHP tutorial while they might be discounted around Christmas ;)

Comment: Doesnt seem to work please check first post i edited it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    foreach ($arrayName as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['Name'] . '<br>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work i edited first post please check it.

Comment: Replace `name` by `Name`. PHP variables and array keys are case sensitive.

Comment: Still doesnt work. I think it runs this command first ''print_r( $Query->GetPlayers( ) );'' and yours isnt running afterwards.

Comment: Edited my answer .. please check it out now

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @yivi sure will take care of it in future.

Comment: You can still edit this one. No need to wait for “the future”.

Comment: Doesnt work. This is the whole code inlcuding yours.
https://pastebin.com/5CpdfVUN

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP function `array_column` to extract only the player names out of the inner arrays: [array_column documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$playerNames = array_column($Query->GetPlayers( ), 'Name');
```

The resulting array will now only contain the Names, which you can print out.